# HyperLink Error: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: asp.net, nullreferenceexception

I've been racking my brain on and off for almost 2 weeks on this one.  I can't figure out why I'm getting this error... any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code behind is as follows:

```
   Protected Sub TaxSaleGridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles TaxSaleGridView.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim LocationMapHyperLink As HyperLink = CType(e.Row.FindControl("OtherParcel"), HyperLink)


        OPval = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, Data.DataRowView)("OtherParcel").ToString()
        PIDval = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, Data.DataRowView)("Property_ID").ToString()


        If Len(OPval) > 1 Then

            e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
            LocationMapHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/index.html?parcel=" & OPval

        Else

            e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.YellowGreen
            LocationMapHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/index.html?parcel=" & PIDval

        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Here is my Markup:

```
 <asp:HyperLink ID="LocationMapHyperLink" runat="server"                

    NavigateUrl=""
    Text="Location Map" 
    Target="_blank">

 </asp:HyperLink><br />
```

Here is the error with stack trace:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Source Error: 


Line 359:                e.Row.Cells(3).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow
Line 360:
Line 361:                LocationMapHyperLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.mydomain.com/index.html?parcel=" & OPval
Line 362:
Line 363:                LocationMapHyperLin.NavigateUrl = String.Format("http://www.mydomain.com/index.html?parcel{0}", OPval)


Source File: C:\DOTNET\TaxSale\Default.aspx.vb    Line: 361 

Stack Trace: 


[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   _Default.TaxSaleGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) in C:\DOTNET\TaxSale\Default.aspx.vb:361
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) +0
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]     fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource) +306
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding) +4603
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +93
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data) +17
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data) +181
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +273
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +104
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls() +169
   System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls() +181
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.get_Rows() +53
   _Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\DOTNET\TaxSale\Default.aspx.vb:173
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +70
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3063
```

Here is the markup for TaxSaleGridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="TaxSaleGridView" onrowdatabound="TaxSaleGridview_RowDataBound" 
    runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataSourceID="TaxSaleDataDS" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" PageSize="30" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
    AllowPaging="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />

    <Columns>        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sale ID">            
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPROPERTYID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROPERTYID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="center" />
                <%Response.Write(startP_bold)%><asp:Label ID="LabelPROPERTYID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROPERTYID") %>'></asp:Label><%Response.Write(endP_bold)%><br />

                <%If Session(existsOtherParcel) = "N" Then%>
                <asp:Panel ID="pnlNotOnSale1" runat="server">
                <asp:Label ID="lblNotOnSale1" runat="server" Text="***Land is not on sale.***" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>
                </asp:Panel>

                <%Else%>

                <%End If%>


            </ItemTemplate>
            <ControlStyle Width="150px" />
            <HeaderStyle Width="150px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="*Minimum Sale Price" ItemStyle-Width="80" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxATSALE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ATSALE") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>                                   
                $<asp:Label ID="LabelATSALE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ATSALE") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Property Information and Address" ItemStyle-Width="400">

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNAME1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME1") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelNAME1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("NAME1") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="LabelLEGAL_DESC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LEGAL_DESC") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="LabelPROP_ADDR1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROP_ADDR1") %>'></asp:Label>, 
                <%Response.Write(startZ_bold)%><asp:Label ID="LabelLocation_Zip" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_Zip") %>'></asp:Label><%Response.Write(endZ_bold)%><br />
                <%Response.Write(startC_bold)%>City: <asp:Label ID="LabelLocation_City" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Location_City") %>'></asp:Label><%Response.Write(endC_bold)%><br />                    
                <%Response.Write(startT_bold)%>Taxing District: <asp:Label ID="LabelTax_District_Name" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Tax_District_Name") %>'></asp:Label><%Response.Write(endT_bold)%>
            </ItemTemplate>
```

```
        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="LEGAL_DESC" HeaderText="LEGAL_DESC" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PROP_ADDR1" HeaderText="PROP_ADDR1" Visible="False" />            
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location_City" HeaderText="Location_City" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Location_Zip" HeaderText="Location_Zip" Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Tax_District_Name" HeaderText="Tax_District_Name" Visible="False" />--%>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="OtherParcel" Visible="true">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxOtherParcel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OtherParcel") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelOtherParcel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("OtherParcel") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reference Materials" ItemStyle-Width="80px" ShowHeader="True" Visible="True">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <!--<%If Session(existsOtherParcel) = "Y" Then%>
            OP exists? <%Response.Write(Session(existsOtherParcel))%><br /><br />
            <%End If%>
            OPval = <%Response.Write(OPval)%><br />
            PIDval = <%Response.Write(PIDval)%><br /><br />-->
                <asp:HyperLink ID="LocationMapHyperLink" runat="server"                

                 NavigateUrl=" "
                 Text="Location Map" Target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,width=780,height=550,left=20,top=20');">

                </asp:HyperLink><br />                  
          <br /> <%'Response.Write(hrefvalue)%> <br /><br />
                <asp:HyperLink ID="PRCHyperLink" runat="server" 
                    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("UnformattedParcelNumber", "http://www2.hamiltoncounty.in.gov/apps/reports/rptpropcard.asp?sparcelno={0}&stemp=&dSearch=houseno&dreport=propcard&report=&dReportName=Property Card") %>' 
                    Text="Property Record Card" Target="_blank" onclick="javascript:window.open(this.href, '','toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,copyhistory=yes,width=780,height=550,left=20,top=20');">
                </asp:HyperLink>
                <br />
            </ItemTemplate>                
           <ItemStyle Width="80px"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:TemplateField>        
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" 
        NextPageText="Next" Position="TopAndBottom" 
        PreviousPageText="Previous" PageButtonCount="1" 
        Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageImageUrl="~/images/misc/first.png" 
        LastPageImageUrl="~/images/misc/last.png" 
        NextPageImageUrl="~/images/misc/next.png" 
        PreviousPageImageUrl="~/images/misc/previous.png" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Right" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Medium" BackColor="#F5F0DC" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F5F0DC" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
```

When I comment out the LocationMapHyperLink.NavigateUrl portion of the code behind, I get the gridview to display showing no null values in the OtherParcel column, and the backgrounds of the cells changing based on the repsective value.

Here is a link to a snippet of the gridview: 
http://i1132.photobucket.com/albums/m561/joelschmidt/taxsalegridview.jpg

Comment: check if the index e.Row.Cells(3) is proper ??

Comment: Please post the Parent Server control of LocationMapHyperLink.

Comment: can you post the markup for TaxSaleGridView?

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: The Gridview is referencing an SQL table... and for testing purposes, I've made sure that there are no NULL values in the OtherParcel column by replacing all of them with a 0 (zero).  However, I'm still getting the error.

Comment: "This question already has an answer here: What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it? 14 answers " -- John, I don't mean to sound crass, but which of the 14 answers specifically address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have a strong suspicion that your `e.Row` only contains 3 cells, thus it should be:
    e.Row.Cells(2)

Remember: indices start at 0 and not at 1.

Comment: -1: that would get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`, not a `NullReferenceException`.